# Pause screen script doesn't work since it doesn't display my game object as active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

I wanted to make a simple pause screen for my unity game, however, when i press the intended button (p) it doesn't display and it's not set as active.

[Here's an image of the script which i haven't finished yet since i just wanted to display the pause menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKaeL.png)

Code excerpt:

```
using UnityEngine
public class pauseManager : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject pauseScreen;

   void Start()
   {
      pause();
   }
   
   void Update()
   {
      if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
      {
        pause();
      }
   }

    public void pause()
    {
        pauseScreen.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

I set the gameobject that controls the pause screen as not active, so that when the game starts, it is not displayed, and i also used that game object in the pauseScreen variable.

Comment: Update does not run on gameobjects that are not active.  Please add code as text, not as images.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: As @hijinxbassist says it sounds like this script is attached to the pause menu object itself -> since you initially disabled it according to your description the `Update` is never running -> not handling your button click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to check for keyboard input using the update function on a disabled object. This does not work because update does not run on game objects that are disabled. In order to work around this you will need to create an always active GameObject to control your pause screen.

Here is a possible fix:

1. Create a separate game object that can run the update method at all times and attatch a new C# script there
2. In the new C# script Create a reference in your script to the pause screen object GameObject you created

```cs
[SerializeField] private Gameobject pauseScreen;
```

3. Now in your update method for this script we check if the 'P' key is pressed. If it is pressed we toggle the pause screen object's active state.

```cs
private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(Keycode.P))
        pauseScreen.setActive(!pauseScreen.ActiveSelf);
    }
}
```

Hopefully this should work for you.

Comment: Thank you! it works now, just one more question, why should i write "!pauseScreen.ActiveSelf" instead of just "True"?

Comment: That's a great question @AndreaColombo! True would work just fine, but `!pauseScreen.ActiveSelf` works as a toggle. `activeSelf` is true only if the game object is active and therefore we tell it to do the inverse of it's current state with the not operator `!`